# how to know which video is selected when ids are dynamic, video list fetch from rest api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api

I am trying to create an easy video player like youtube, I am using rest API for videos list, and the problem is that i don't know which video is selected in the list, to show that in the main frame. I mean, I get video Id from API and how to know which one is clicked. (javascript or jquery)

```
response.forEach(function (post) {
        output += `
            <p > <video width="100%" onclick="PlayVideo()" >
            <source src="${post.url}" type="video/MP4" id="${post.id}"/>
              </video></p>
            `
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a reference of the triggering element to the function.

```
response.forEach(function (post) {

  // "this" is passed as an argument
  output += `
    <p > <video width="100%" onclick="PlayVideo(this)" >
    <source src="${post.url}" type="video/MP4" id="${post.id}"/>
    </video></p>
  `
});
```

Then in the function:

```
PlayVideo(element){
  //...
  var triggeringID = element.id;
  console.log("Triggering element's ID: " + triggeringID;  // You have it here...
}
```